# Http get request is getting completed later than scope is getting values in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been working on Angular JS project.

In this, I need to call a get method to fetch some records, then I need to assign the response to scope variable and display it to User.

But my problem is HTTP get request is getting completed late. So my scope's value is coming undefined.

below is my code controller code:

```
var app = angular.module('falconeApp',[]);

app.controller("logicCtrl",['$scope','getDestinationService', function($scope, getDestinationService){      
    $scope.destinations = getDestinationService.getDestinations();
}]);

app.factory("getDestinationService",function($http, $q){
    var getDestinationApi = "https://findfalcone.herokuapp.com/planets";
    return {
        getDestinations: function(){
            $http.get(getDestinationApi)
            .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        }
    }
});
```

So, as you can see in the above case, **$scope.destinations** is coming undefined as HTTP request is getting completed later than assigning the value to it.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: @Izagkaretos No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a promise callback in the controller side as well.

> The then() method returns a Promise.The Promise object is used for
>   deferred and asynchronous computations. A Promise represents an
>   operation that hasn't completed yet, but is expected in the future.

```
app.controller("logicCtrl", ['$scope', 'getDestinationService', function($scope, getDestinationService) {

  $scope.getDestinations = function() {
    getDestinationService.getDestinations().then(function(res) {
      $scope.destinations = res;
    });
  };

  $scope.getDestinations();

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your calling function as below,

```
getDestinationService.getDestinations().then(response_data=>{
    $scope.destinations = response_data;
}).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
});
```

$http.get is a promise and hence you can always catch the response in .then which will solve your problem.